# Android - Create Repeating Notification At Set Time

Tags: android, time, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have looked through a ton of documentation and stackoverflow questions on how to set a repeating notification set to a certain time but can not get any of them to work. Here is what I have right now.

The method I set up the AlarmManager in:

```
//set alarm method
private void setAlarm() {
    if(enableCheckBox.isChecked()) {
        //save time / title / message
        mTinyDB.putInt(Constants.SAVED_HOUR, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
        mTinyDB.putInt(Constants.SAVED_MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
        mTinyDB.putString(Constants.SAVED_TITLE, titleEditText.getText().toString().trim());
        mTinyDB.putString(Constants.SAVED_MESSAGE, messageEditText.getText().toString().trim());
        mTinyDB.putBoolean(Constants.SAVED_NOTIFICATION_ENABLED, enableCheckBox.isChecked());

        //create repeating notification
        Intent intent = new Intent(NotificationActivity.this, Notify.class);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                0, intent, 0);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mTinyDB.getInt(Constants.SAVED_HOUR, 0));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,  mTinyDB.getInt(Constants.SAVED_MINUTE, 0));
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

The Notify class which extends BoradcastReceiver:

```
public class Notify extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TinyDB mTinyDB = new TinyDB(context);
    Notification builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(mTinyDB.getString(Constants.SAVED_TITLE))
            .setContentText(mTinyDB.getString(Constants.SAVED_MESSAGE))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_check)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder);
}
```

}

Am I doing this completely wrong? I can't get anything to come up (at least at the set time). Help or guidance is appreciated :)

Comment: Is your receiver registered and [exported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)?

Comment: I don't know what that means. Could you explain?

Comment: Any component that the system needs to access whether it is a activity, service, or receiver needs to be registered in the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `PendingIntent.getService`, but your intent is not for a service. For a `BroadcastReceiver`, you should be using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: You shouldn't add another answer. You should just edit your original answer and add this bit too!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that you can't set an *exact*, repeatable alarm in Android. If you want your repeating alarm to occur at an exact time, you must set a one time exact alarm and recreate it after the alarm goes off in your code.

Citation: [Documentation for setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: That's weird because so many other places online make it seem easily possible with setRepeating()

Comment: This was a change in API 19 (KitKat, Android 4.4). Those examples were probably targeting an API older than 19.

Comment: Ohhhh, I have API 21. That might be why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the system to be able to launch a component, it should be registered in your manifest:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage.myapplication" >
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".Notify" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: added it and still doesn't work. I think it's a problem in the code I posted.

Comment: Well, if you had to add it, then that should solve one of your problems.